# mail() Prevents JSON Response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using the following jQuery code to send form data to a PHP handling script which either enters a new listing in a data base or updates an existing listing.

The site lists boats and yachts for sale. It is/was working great, but now the client wants to get a email notice when a new boat is listed. I added code to the PHP handling script to do that, but if I use `mail()` for some reason it stops the success function from working in the jQuery code below.

The `mail()` function is the only thing that effects it. If I comment that line out it works again.

Any ideas of what is happening?

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "scripts/listing_form_json_exec.php", 
        dataType: 'json',   
        data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
        success: function(data) { 
            var yacht_id = (data);
            $('#manage_images_link').attr('href', 'manage_images.php?yacht_id=' + yacht_id);                
            $('input[name=yacht_id]').val(yacht_id);
            $('img.saved').show();
            $('img.saved').fadeOut(3000);
            $('div#button_frame').show();
            $('#errors_container').html('');

        } 
    });
```

EDIT

The PHP script is very long, but here is the offending part

```
    $_SESSION['SESS_YAUCHT_ID'] = $yacht_id;
echo json_encode($yacht_id);

if (isset($message)) {
    //mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

I tried putting the `mail()` function in different places, but no matter where I put it the same thing happens. Above I have the `mail()` function commented out and everything works. If I uncomment it the script stops working.

Comment: Show the PHP script. It's probably printing an error, which is interfering with the JSON.

Comment: Also, check your server error logs for PHP errors on the mail() call.

Comment: Do you have a working mail program running on the server, or your localhost, if that is where you are testing it.

Comment: Try to use Chrome Developer tools or Firebug. Check the network tab for the ajax request and see what result you get. Most probably there's an error, debug output or similar there.

Comment: Since commenting out the `mail()` makes it work, most likely that's where your error is.

Comment: see edit above, thanks for the help, even if I have it uncommented, the rest of the script is working and doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: As a rule of thumb for my recent web projects, I now most often offload processing not needed for page rendering to asynchronous workers, using software like Redis or Gearman. This allows for better load management and improves response times, if done well.

Comment: you're are right that is a typo but I checked and I have the same typo everywhere so that isn't what is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
$_SESSION['SESS_YAUCHT_ID'] = $yacht_id;
echo json_encode($yacht_id);

if (isset($message)) {
    if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            //ok
    } else {
            //error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that since I was testing locally, it wasn't connecting to the mail server, once I
uploaded it to the server everything works.

Thanks for the suggestions, as it turns out it was something silly.